# webpack symfony encore jquery third party plugins

Tags: symfony, webpack, jquery-validate

i am having problem with implementing jquery 3rd party plugins in symfony webpack encore.
so far i have several .js files with varous logic, and also some scripts inside twig files that execute some of js.

this is app.js :

```
var $ = require('jquery');
global.$ = global.jQuery = global.jquery = $;
require('jquery-validation');
```

webpack compiles, but when i execute program i get:

$(...).validate is not a function

webpack.config.js is straightforward:

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
// directory where compiled assets will be stored
.setOutputPath('public/build/')
// public path used by the web server to access the output path
.setPublicPath('/build')
.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

.addEntry('base', './assets/js/base.js')

.splitEntryChunks()
.enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
;
module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

package.json:

```
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
"jquery-validation": "^1.18.0",
"jquery-datetimepicker": "^2.5.20",
```

update: 
jquery-datetimepicker is working fine,
but jquery-validation is not!

Comment: Where is it defined as “jquery-validation”?   Plugin is called “jQuery Validate”.

Comment: @Sparky IDE's autocomplete just gives that based on npm_modules directory listings and that parts seems correct

Comment: I would not assume that.  There are several plugins with similar name.

Answer (score 0):

solution:
update webpack.config.js with alias information, so that every jquery 3rd party plugin uses same jquery

```
var path = require('path');

Encore
    .addAliases({
        'jquery': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/jquery/src/jquery')
    })
```

Comment: This isn't the issue either.  The problem isn't 3rd party plugins can't find $ or jQuery.  It's about the 3rd party plugin not being defined... which it absolutely should be if you look through the compiled webpack JS.

Comment: @tlorens I think it might actually be about plugins not tying into the correct jQuery. I had another bundle (EasyAdminBundle) that already loaded jQuery: `global.$ = global.jQuery = require('jquery');` , which was slightly different from my own `app.js`: `const $ = require('jquery');`. When I used the EasyAdminBundle method, my JQuery UI plugin of choice suddenly started working

Answer (score -2):

from: https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/legacy-apps.html

#### jQuery Plugins and Legacy Applications

Inside Webpack, when you require a module, it does not (usually) set a global variable. Instead, it just returns a value:

```
// this loads jquery, but does *not* set a global $ or jQuery variable
const $ = require('jquery');
```

...

#### Fixing jQuery Plugins that Expect jQuery to be Global

jQuery plugins often expect that jQuery is already available via the $ or jQuery global variables. To fix this, call autoProvidejQuery() from your webpack.config.js file:

```
Encore
    // ...
   .autoProvidejQuery()    // add this line into your webpack.config.js file
;
```

#### Accessing jQuery from outside of Webpack JavaScript Files

If your code needs access to $ or jQuery and you are inside of a file that's processed by Webpack/Encore, you should remove any "$ is not defined" errors by requiring jQuery: var $ = require('jquery').

But if you also need to provide access to $ and jQuery variables outside of JavaScript files processed by Webpack (e.g. JavaScript that still lives in your templates), you need to manually set these as global variables in some JavaScript file that is loaded before your legacy code.

For example, in your app.js file that's processed by Webpack and loaded on every page, add:

```
// require jQuery normally
const $ = require('jquery');

+ // create global $ and jQuery variables
+ global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
```

Comment: indeed, i read documentation and to further comment on this issue:
i think it is issue with jquery-validate, 
since i see that package 'jquery-datetimepicker' is doing fine. 
any thoughts on that? 
i'll edit initial  question as well

oh and btw that's without using
.autoProvidejQuery() since it messes configuration

Comment: All of the above is great and dandy for getting jQuery working and writing code against it (ie. $('button').on('click')....). But this answer doesn't address anything about add-ons/plugins which leverage jQuery and error out as being undefined $('table').footable() doesn't work. as ...function footable() is undefined. The question is about getting 3rd party plug-ins to work, not jQuery.